# Using setProperties on EntityManager doesn't create dataServiceAdapterInstance

Tags: breeze

In my application, we were creating an instance of the `EntityManager` with no properties, and then later setting properties using the `setProperties` method of the `EntityManager`. I ran into a problem however in that when you use `setProperties` and give it a service name, it doesn't set the `dataServiceAdpterInstance` property on the `EntityManager`, this causes all queries to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding `this.dataServiceAdapterInstance = a_config.getAdapterInstance("dataService");` from the *EntityManager* constructor into the *setProperties* method.

Comment: @JoRouss Please do not use code formatting to simply highlight key words, class names, and the like. It should only be used for actual code fragments. In the above post, it was not correct to use code formatting for 'EntityManager' or 'setProperties'. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edits Andrew. I'll use the formats per your edits moving forward.